# Custom Divi Module Displaying Custom Post Type Instead of Default Post

Tags: wordpress, post, types, module

I am trying to make a Divi custom module that is modeled off the existing blog module. So far so good with thanks to the following link: https://jonathanbossenger.com/building-your-own-divi-builder-modules/

I'm at a loss as to where I can 'filter' or set the 'post-type' to my 'custom post' type instead of the default 'post'.

I have tried the following:

```
// trying for post type`
$query_args['post_type'] = ['title_author'];
```

This is shown here: https://pastebin.com/Ey8zdBkN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `$args['post_type'] = array( 'your_post_type' );` to the `shortcode_callback`function right before `ob_start();` First make sure your custom module is loading properly.